# jquery 'click' event inside the for loop

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I want to do task like pagination in javascript.This is my code.

```
for(var i=1;i<=total_guest;i++)
{   
$("#Personal"+i).find("#Personal_details ").show();
$('#Personal'+i).find('.personal_info').click(function(e){
    alert(i);
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#Personal"+i).find("#Personal_details ").hide();


    }); 
}
```

Explanation:

In loop i am getting total_guest value(example 5). At starting i want to get page for first guest.when i click next button(class='personal_info') i should show page for next guest like wise till 5th guest.

Can any one give solution?

**EDIT to include HTML:**

```
<div id='Personal1' > 
    <div id='Personal_details'> 
        <div class='personal_info'>button for next step</div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div id='Personal2' > 
    <div id='Personal_details'> 
        <div class='personal_info'>button for next step</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML or describe it? The IDs do not make it entirely clear which elements are your "pages".

Comment: <div id='Personal1' >
    <div id='Personal_details'>
           <div class='personal_info'>button for next step</div>
    </div>                                                                      
</div>
<div id='Personal2' >
    <div id='Personal_details'>
           <div class='personal_info'>button for next step</div>
    </div>  
</div>                                                                                                                                    I typed this manually.I assure these are the correct elements What i have in my source

Comment: @DurgaGanesh Please use the edit button to add to your question; I added the HTML from your comment to your original question, where it is much easier to read.

Comment: `id`s should be unique in the document, you have multiple elements with the id `Personal_details`!!

Comment: ya thanks for this suggestion.i will follow.

Comment: @DurgaGanesh Does this sample solve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Eh8hk/

Comment: @Arun P Johny. I did cloning.if i use class value for div then is gets multiple clone instead single.then what is the better way to achieve my concept.The concept is when user selects 3 guests then i should get 3 personal detail page(like pagination i.e click next button should show next personal detail page)

Comment: how are you cloning it?

Comment: @Arun P Johny. thanks for this jsfiddle example.it really does the need

Answer (score 2):

To make your loop work, you need a closure to keep the value of `i` constant inside the click function, but it all seems uneccessary, as you could just do:

```
$(".Personal_details").show().on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Note that ID's are unique, and `.find(someID)` does'nt make sense, as there can be only one element with that ID.

**EDIT:** Based on the new HTML, that's an error! You ***can not*** have the same ID twice (or more).

```
<div id='Personal1' > 
    <div class='Personal_details'> 
        <div class='personal_info'>button for next step</div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div id='Personal2' > 
    <div class='Personal_details'> 
        <div class='personal_info'>button for next step</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My ids are '#Personal1','#Personal2','#Personal3' etc as per user selection.I want loop to increment the number.

Comment: Then why are you targeting it, the selector is looking for an element with that ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,change id to class for instance `id="Personal1" to class="personal"`  then

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('.personal').click(function() {
           $(this).children('.personal-details').show();
    });

    $('.personal_info').click(function() {
           $(this).parent().hide();
           $(this).parent().parent().next().children('.personal-details').show();
    });
});
```